Surely $\rm CO_2$ reflects incoming solar infrared radiation?
Is the greenhouse effect not cancelled out by the $\rm CO_2$ in the atmosphere reflecting solar infrared radiation back into space? It seems logical to me that, if $\rm CO_2$ reflects infrared shifted from the visible spectrum reflected from Earth's surface, that that same $\rm CO_2$ would reflect infrared coming from the Sun, and this would cancel out the greenhouse effect. Am I wrong to think this?

Is the greenhouse effect in a real greenhouse (which is much easier to understand than the "greenhouse effect" in Earth's atmosphere) cancelled by the fact the glass windows reflect part of the incoming radiation?

Most of the incoming solar radiation is in the visible, where CO$_2$ is transparent. The radiation is absorbed by the ground and warms it. The ground radiates in the infrared.
Without CO$_2$, the infrared radiation carries away energy into space. This cools the ground.
CO$_2$ is opaque in the infrared. With CO$_2$ present, the infrared radiation does not reach space. It warms the CO$_2$, which keeps the ground warmer than it would be.

This isn't the truth; most solar radiation is in the infrared. We've known since the mid-nineties that the Sun emits mostly in the infrared part of the spectrum. We know CO_2 must reflect incoming infrared radiation also, which would cancel out the effect from infrared coming from the ground.

@EschatonMagazine Even a cursory look at the solar spectrum will tell you that the solar peak is in the green. Roughly half of the power is in the visible and UV, most of the remainder is in the near IR at 1um. The absorption bands of CO2 at at long IR wavelengths around 4um and 15um. I don't know where you are getting your ideas from, but it is not from science textbooks.

On Wikipedia, I found https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/CO2_H2O_absorption_atmospheric_gases_unique_pattern_energy_wavelengths_of_energy_transparent_to_others.png , which compares absorption  of water vapor and carbon dioxide by wavelength. But doing some computations based on that, it cannot be true.

But we do find radiation coming from the Sun in the range between 4 um and 15 um. No, my science information wasn't coming from textbooks, it was coming from NASA.https://sunclimate.gsfc.nasa.gov/article/solar-irradiance

@EschatonMagazine in fact your link already shows the answer to your question which supports most of the above answer. The orange parts of the plot already take into account that which doesn't reach the earths surface as compared to the yellow which is at the top of the atmosphere (ToA). As can be seen $CO_2$ is transparent to most of the light reaching the surface.

@EschatonMagazine, You are correct in that the Sun emits some radiation between 4 and 15 microns. But, if you apply Planck's Radiation Law to the problem, you will see that the fraction of the Sun's total output at those wavelengths is very small as compared to the fraction that is emitted at shorter wavelengths. If you don't want to do the math yourself, have a look at this graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#/media/File:Black_body.svg (Keep in mind that the temperature of the Sun's photosphere is approximately 5000K.)

I have my own misgivings about that. The Planck radiation law can be used given the assumption that the emitted light from the Sun is a constant. We don't see (dramatic) changes in the Sun's output on the surface of the Sun, but the Sun's corona is different. It could be that we're travelling through clouds of interstellar dust, gas, rock, etc, and that this burns up on the Sun's corona without getting near the Sun's surface. In this case, the warming we see on Earth could come from moving through areas of especially high density of gas/dust.


Is the greenhouse effect not cancelled out by the $\rm CO_2$ in the atmosphere reflecting solar infrared radiation back into space?

No.
The idea that the greenhouse effect is caused and controlled by infrared radiation being absorbed by $\rm CO_2$ in the atmosphere and re-radiated downwards is not correct, because it ignore the overriding effects of convection. The greenhouse effect in a convective atmosphere is a combination of two effects: radiative equilibrium to space, and the adiabatic lapse rate.
First, by energy balance, the amount of energy entering the Earth's system is almost identical to the amount of energy leaving it. The only significant source of energy is sunlight, and the only significant ways for it to escape are by reflection of shortwave (visible) light from clouds, ice, and the surface, and infrared blackbody radiation from the sun-warmed radiating surface of the Earth. By measuring how much visible light arrives and is reflected (with satellites) we know how much is absorbed, and therefore how much is radiated as infrared. To radiate this amount of energy, the surface of the Earth radiating to space has to be at about $-20^\circ$C on average. The critical point to note is that this radiating surface is not the ground/ocean, but spread out through the moist $10$ km thick lower atmosphere. If you could see the Earth from space with eyes that see infrared, the atmosphere would be a fuzzy opaque ball, and the infrared light you see would come from about 5 km up on average. This is the level that settles out at $-20^\circ$C.
Second, gases warm up when they are compressed, and cool down when they are allowed to expand. So as air rises and falls in the circulating atmosphere, it cools as it rises and warms up as it descends. This creates a vertical temperature gradient in the atmosphere, called the adiabatic lapse rate. When we add the effect of water vapour condensing and evaporating, the result is a temperature gradient of about $6.5^\circ$C/km. For every km you descend, the temperature rises $6.5^\circ$C.
These two effects combine. Radiative balance to outer space holds the temperature $5$ km up at $-20^\circ$C, and air descending from this altitude is warmed $5\times 6.5=32.5^\circ$C down to the surface. That puts the surface at about $12.5^\circ$C on average. (All figures are approximate - in detail it is a lot more complicated than this simplified outline.)
When the concentration of infrared-opaque gases in the atmosphere (mainly water vapour and carbon dioxide) increases, the average altitude of IR-emission to space rises, and so the amount of pressure-related warming down to the surface increases, warming the surface.
All the incoming infrared is absorbed by the Earth (whether in the atmosphere or at the surface) and so the amount of $\rm CO_2$ in the atmosphere does not change the total amount of energy absorbed and re-radiated by the Earth system. Hence the answer to your question is 'No'.
--
However, the climate is much more complicated than this, and there are lots of feedbacks going on that mean you can't possibly use such a simplified model to predict the dynamic effects of changes to $\rm CO_2$. For example, the equatorial ocean warms each morning in the sun until it reaches about $27^\circ$C when it suddenly forms thunderstorms, increasing the amount of shortwave visible light reflected back to space. (Similarly to your proposal, although with visible light and not infrared.) On warm days, the clouds form earlier in the day, giving a greater cooling effect. On cool days they form later, allowing things to warm more. It acts like a thermostat, adjusting the amount of heat absorbed at the equator to keep the temperature roughly constant.
You can think of it as a bit like a pan of boiling water, that stays at a constant $100^\circ$C, no matter how you turn the heat up or down. More heat just drives faster convection and heat transfer. It is highly non-linear.
You have to think about the effects on clouds, ice coverage at the poles, equator-to-pole circulation, water vapour levels, ocean heat and circulation, reflection from vegetation/desert, and hundreds of other variables. Much of it is poorly-understood. Our best understanding, trying to take everything we know about into account, is that there will very likely be a temperature rise, but the errors bars on how much are massive.
--
It may be objected that although the convective adiabatic lapse rate makes a contribution, that the back-radiation coming down from the sky is the driving mechanism. To see why this doesn't work, we can consider how the greenhouse effect works in a shallow pool of water. This too is transparent to visible light, but liquid water absorbs all radiated infrared within a fraction of a millimetre. Thus sunlight shines down and is absorbed at the bottom of the pool. This radiates upwards and is immediately absorbed by the layer of water immediately above. This radiates up and down, and again the upward radiation is absorbed. It is a simple matter of energy balance to show that the power emitted rises linearly with depth, and hence the temperature rises with the fourth root of depth (due to the Stefan-Boltzmann law). This would mean that with only a very shallow depth, the oceans would boil!
This does not happen in practice because convection transports deep heat up to the surface faster than it can accumulate. As water is virtually incompressible, you get virtually no pressure-related warming with depth, and you don't see a significant greenhouse effect in water, despite the fact that you do very definitely get strong infrared absorption and downward back-radiation from the water above.

That's a very honest appraisal of climate science, thank you for giving such an informed response. I've heard the argument from convection before, but I'm still inclined to disagree. I think you said it yourself when you mentioned the fact that incoming versus outgoing radiation to/from Earth is more or less the same. I take that to imply that most of the solar infrared is indeed reflected by (various) things in our atmosphere, including CO_2 of course. You're right, much of this science is "poorly understood" and I think we have a way to go on this issue of climate change.

"so the amount of CO2 in the atmosphere does not change the total amount of energy absorbed and re-radiated by the Earth system" this is exactly what I would have predicted. Did you mean to say this? Surely, this means that the answer to my question is "yes" not "no".
